# Error: The argument type 'String?' and The method 'readAsBytes' isn't defined for the type 'File'

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hi I got the error The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'. and The method 'readAsBytes' isn't defined for the type 'File'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'readAsBytes'.

Code:

```
Future startFilePicker(String fileNotes, BuildContext context) async {
  List<int> selectedFile;
  Uint8List bytesData;
  String selectedDocumentName = "Unspecified";
  File selectedDocument;

  FilePickerResult? result;
  if (io.Platform.isWindows) {
    if (fileNotes.toLowerCase() == 'photos') {
      result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.media);
    } else if (fileNotes.toLowerCase() == 'radiology') {
      result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.media);
    } else {
      result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    }
  } else {
    result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
  }

  if (result != null) {
    PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
    selectedDocument = File(file.path);
    selectedDocumentName = file.name;
    selectedFile = [];
    bytesData = await selectedDocument.readAsBytes();
    selectedFile = bytesData;
    await uploadFile(selectedDocument, selectedFile, context, fileNotes,
        selectedDocumentName, selectedDocumentName);
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: *Which* `File` class are you using?  The one from `dart:io`?  from `dart:html`? from `package:file`? from somewhere else?  Given your errors, you're probably using [the one from `dart:html`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-html/File-class.html), but you're trying to use it as the one from `dart:io`.  They are completely separate, unrelated classes.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter for `File` constructor cannot be null so if your class `PlatformFile` `path` parameter is nullable you need to change this or perform a nullcheck and force the parameter with `!` mark.

ReadAsBytes may not work in this scenario because there is no file to read as bytes. You are passing a path that may be null so no file is available to read as bytes.